# How to check the cause of Access SysCmd fail in VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

We have an application developed in VB.NET as well as in VBA in the client. In a installer custom action developed in VB.NET we compile mdb file to mde using the Access's SysCmd 603 which is famously undocumented. The sample code looks like this:

```
a = CreateObject("Access.Application")
If a.SysCmd(603, PATH_TO_BXB_FILE, PATH_TO_BXE_FILE) = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Fail to compile to MDB file")
End If
```

This code worked before until recently. Now the Syscmd call returned 0 which indicates the compile failed. But since I am not familiar with Access programming, I don't know how to check further the cause of this fail. In this link [Application.SysCmd Method (Access)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193809.aspx) it says it will generate a run-time error in case of failing, but I don't know how to check this error. Please help

Comment: Maybe it can be done via try-catch in vb.net, so in catch code msgbox will pop up the exception.Message?

Comment: @johnyTee Thanks for your swift reply. But I have already tried this intuitive method, and it doesn't throw a System.Exeception. It just simply returns 0. I am guessing it will write down the cause of the error somewhere else.

Comment: Working off my own copy of 2010 MS Access and this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/6d0133ed-b8a8-46bb-aa48-bd40c9b41231/, Syscmd runs. Does your mdb contain code? Does the code sompile clean? The link suggest that Syscmd is of limited use in automation.

Comment: OK, I found this under note on page you posted link to: 'If the object referred to by the objectname argument is either not open or doesn't exist, the SysCmd method returns a value of zero.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 603 argument of [syscmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa199129%28v=office.10%29.aspx) is undocumented. It will fail for a number of reasons, for example, running under VBA it will fail if you do not use a separate instance of MS Access. In [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/6d0133ed-b8a8-46bb-aa48-bd40c9b41231/), other reason to fail are given as:

> - when it's used in VBA code running in a separate Access database (separate from the solution database);
> - when the solution database is closed; and
> - when there are no syntax errors in the VBA code in the solution database.

The document also lists these references:

> Douglas Steele makes an interesting point here:
>   http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2621925.php
>   Tony Toews investigates undocumented SysCmds here:
>   https://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/2007/08/19/so-what-are-the-undocumented-syscmd-items.aspx
>   Tony Toews also links to this page:
>   http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Undocumented-SysCmd-Functions

Comment: Thanks Remou. I solved this problem based on your comment on my question post: my mdb file contains code and there is two references missing. When I open the mdb file in Access and tried to compile it, I see this reference missing warning. After I corrected it, the compilation went through and so did the SysCmd call