# Access 2007 Make ACCDE from VBA SysCmd 603

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to automate the tasks I would normally run through to compact my database, save backups, and update revision numbers for an automatic update system I am using. I am stuck on trying to make an accde file with a vba script.

Everything I find pertaining to the subject seems to point to using something like this.

```
function MakeACCDE(InPath As String, OutPath As String)

Dim app As New Access.Application

app.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

app.SysCmd 603, InPath, OutPath

End Function
```

A few users on various forums claim that this code works for them but I have not had any luck. My database runs the code without errors, but nothing actually happens.

Is there a particular piece of syntax I am not using or maybe something with the format of the file paths?

Comment: Take a look at this article on Stack - possibly missing references?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195275/how-to-check-the-cause-of-access-syscmd-fail-in-vb-net-code

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I haven't figured it out still. I read all of the linked articles on the recommended post, but none of the suggestions seem to change anything. I did double check and make sure that my vba code compiles properly, the database is closed, and the code is being run from a separate database.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following code at: http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28429044/How-do-I-create-an-Access-2010-accde-from-VBA.html

I inserted into my Access 2010 accdb, ran it, and it created an accde

**UPDATE: Seeing you want to run from a different DB, I tested that also... just change the line 'tmpDB_Full_Name = CurrentProject.FullName' to be your source database

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Create_MDE()
 Dim tmpDB_Full_Name As String
    Dim tmpDB_Name As String
    Dim tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name As String
    Dim tmpCopy_File As Variant
    Dim tmpDirectory As String

    'Call SetStartupOptions("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)               '---This runs a procedure to deactivate the Shift & F11 key

    'tmpDB_Full_Name = CurrentProject.FullName
    tmpDB_Full_Name = "C:\data\access\MyDb.accdb"
    tmpDirectory = CurrentProject.Path
    tmpDB_Name = CurrentProject.Name

    tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name = tmpDirectory & "\" & left(tmpDB_Name, Len(tmpDB_Name) - 6) & "-Backup.accdb"

    'this removes a file created on the same day
    If Dir(tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name) <> "" Then

        Kill tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name

    End If

    'this creates a backup into destination tmpDirectory
    If Dir(tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name) = "" Then

        Set tmpCopy_File = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        tmpCopy_File.CopyFile tmpDB_Full_Name, tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name, True

    End If

    Dim app As New Access.Application

    app.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

    app.SysCmd 603, tmpDB_Backup_Full_Name, tmpDirectory & "\" & left(tmpDB_Name, Len(tmpDB_Name) - 9) & ".accde"

    'Call SetStartupOptions("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, True)                 '---This runs a procedure to activate the Shift & F11

    MsgBox ("Compile Complete!")

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and code. I am getting an error "Compile error: Variable not defined" on this line `app.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow`.

What references are you using?

Comment: That is found in the Office 14.0 library.

Comment: I am currently referencing the 12.0 library and am unable to find the 14.0 library in access 2007. I think I may be calling it quits on cracking this one. I automated the rest of the process and this will probably be the one thing I just have to perform manually.

Comment: Don't give up yet! It has to be in Office 12 also. If it's failing due to 'msoAutomationSecurityLow' just use a value of 1 in place of that name. If you go to the code window, press F2, then type in the variable name in the search box and click on the binoculars. I'm guessing you will not find, but ...

Comment: The code above works on access 2016 for me after I replaced msoAutomationSecurityLow by 1 and add a reference to the VB script run-time library. The relevant file is usually located at \Windows\System32\scrrun.dll . merci Wayne

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a ready-made solution that creates an ACCDE file and at the same time allows you to protect it with a password. With frequent updates, it makes my life so much easier. I tested it on *Microsoft Access 2016* and *2019*.

The function *`SaveAccdbAsAccde()`* performs the following steps:

- compiles and saves changes to the database
- copies the database to '...(~temp~).ACCDB'
- creates the file '...(~temp~).ACCDE'
- if everything worked, it sets a password to the database and copies it as the target file
- deletes working files

To protect the database with a password, do the following: *`SaveAccdbAsAccde("password")`*

I used a few functions that might also come in handy for other tasks:

- helper functions based on *`Scripting.FileSystemObject`* for handling files use : *`CopyFile()`*,*`DeleteFile()`*,*`FileExists()`*
- functions to secure / unsecure the database with a password *`EncryptDb()`* and *`DecryptDb()`*

All details below:

```
Option Explicit

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'main function

Public Sub SaveAccdbAsAccde(Optional filePassword As String)
On Error Resume Next

    Application.RunCommand acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules
    err.Clear
    If err <> 0 Then MsgBox "Save changes in forms and reports before preparing the ACCDE file.": Exit Sub

On Error GoTo err_proc

    Dim strFile0 As String, strFile1 As String, strFile2 As String, strFile3 As String
    strFile0 = CurrentDb.Name
    strFile1 = Replace(CurrentDb.Name, ".accdb", "(~temp~).accdb")
    strFile2 = Replace(CurrentDb.Name, ".accdb", "(~temp~).accde")
    strFile3 = Replace(CurrentDb.Name, ".accdb", ".accde")

    If Not DeleteFile(strFile1) Then MsgBox "Can't felete file: " & strFile2: Exit Sub
    If Not CopyFile(strFile0, strFile1) Then MsgBox "Can't copy file: " & strFile0 & " na " & strFile1: Exit Sub
    
    If Not DeleteFile(strFile2) Then MsgBox "Can't delete file: " & strFile2: Exit Sub
    MakeACCDESysCmd strFile1, strFile2
    If Not FileExists(strFile2) Then MsgBox "Can't create file: " & strFile2: Exit Sub
    
    If Not DeleteFile(strFile3) Then MsgBox "Can't delete file: " & strFile3: Exit Sub
    EncryptDb strFile2, strFile3, filePassword
    If Not FileExists(strFile3) Then MsgBox "Can't create file: " & strFile3: Exit Sub
    
    If Not DeleteFile(strFile2) Then MsgBox "Can't delete file: " & strFile2: Exit Sub
    If Not DeleteFile(strFile1) Then MsgBox "Can't delete file: " & strFile2: Exit Sub

MsgBox "Done: " & strFile3

exit_proc:
    Exit Sub
    
err_proc:
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume exit_proc
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub EncryptDb(strSourcePath As String, strDestPath As String, pwd As String)
    If pwd <> "" Then pwd = ";pwd=" & pwd
    DBEngine.CompactDatabase strSourcePath, strDestPath, dbLangGeneral & pwd, dbVersion167, pwd
End Sub

Public Sub DecryptDb(strSourcePath As String, strDestPath As String, pwd As String)
    If pwd <> "" Then pwd = ";pwd=" & pwd
    DBEngine.CompactDatabase strSourcePath, strDestPath, dbLangGeneral & ";pwd=", dbVersion167, pwd
End Sub

Public Function MakeACCDESysCmd(InPath As String, OutPath As String)
    Dim app As Access.Application
    Set app = New Access.Application
    app.AutomationSecurity = 1 'msoAutomationSecurityLow - Enables all macros. This is the default value when the application is started.
    app.SysCmd 603, InPath, OutPath 'an undocumented action
    app.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    Set app = Nothing
End Function

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Function CopyFile(strFromFile, strToFile)
On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    err.Clear
    objFSO.CopyFile strFromFile, strToFile, True
    CopyFile = err = 0
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function

Public Function DeleteFile(strFile)
    If Not FileExists(strFile) Then DeleteFile = True: Exit Function
On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    err.Clear
    objFSO.DeleteFile strFile, True
    DeleteFile = err = 0
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function

Public Function FileExists(strFile)
On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = objFSO.FileExists(strFile)
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following code in Access 2016 using ACCDE and ACCDR as the destination file extension:

```
        Dim otherAccess As Access.Application
        Set otherAccess = New Access.Application
        otherAccess.AutomationSecurity = 1 'msoAutomationSecurityLow
        otherAccess.SysCmd 603, InPath, OutPath
        otherAccess.Quit acQuitSaveNone
        Set otherAccess = Nothing
```